# Bit field's memory management in C

Tags: c, linux, memory

To understand the bit field memory storage, I have created the test program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    typedef struct {
        int b7 : 1;
        int b6 : 1;
        int b5 : 1;
        int b4 : 1;
        int b3 : 1;
        int b2 : 1;
        int b1 : 1;
        int b0 : 1;
    } byte;

    byte ab0 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
    a = *(int*)&ab0;
    printf("ab0 is %x \n",a);

    byte ab1 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0};
    a = *(int*)&ab1;
    printf("ab1 is %x \n",a);

    byte ab2 = {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0};
    a = *(int*)&ab2;
    printf("ab2 is %x \n",a);

    byte ab3 = {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0};
    a = *(int*)&ab3;
    printf("ab3 is %x \n",a);

    byte ab4 = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0};
    a = *(int*)&ab4;
    printf("ab4 is %x \n",a);

    byte ab5 = {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0};
    a = *(int*)&ab5;
    printf("ab5 is %x \n",a);

    byte ab6 = {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    a = *(int*)&ab6;
    printf("ab6 is %x \n",a);

    byte ab7 = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    a = *(int*)&ab7;
    printf("ab7 is %x \n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run

```
gcc -Wall test.c
./a.out 
ab0 is 80 
ab1 is 40 
ab2 is 20 
ab3 is 10 
ab4 is 8 
ab5 is 4 
ab6 is 2 
ab7 is 1
```

Same output when I run code online
http://codepad.org/ntqyuixp

I am not able to understand its output.

**Expected Output:**
As per my understanding output should be like

```
ab0 is 1 
ab1 is 2 
ab2 is 4 
ab3 is 8 
ab4 is 10 
ab5 is 20 
ab6 is 40 
ab7 is 80
```

- Please let me know what I am missing.
- Does endianness play any role?
- How should the code be written for my expected behaviour?

Comment: I know that you only do this for the experiment, but your method of casting to `int*` and then derefferencing is erroneous and will lead you to a lot of trouble if you would apply this in production code. Don't do this. The method that is foreseen by the standard to do inspections like this are `union`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order of the bits in a bit-field is implementation defined.  The implementation has a different definition from the one you expected — and that's almost all there is to say about it.

Almost everything about bit-fields is implementation defined.

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers

> ¶4 The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant
>   expression with a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the
>   type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted.<sup>122)</sup> If the value is
>   zero, the declaration shall have no declarator.
>
> ¶5 A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed
>   int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is
>   implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.
>
> …
>
> ¶9 A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type other than a
>   variably modified type.<sup>123)</sup> In addition, a member may be declared to consist of a
>   specified number of bits (including a sign bit, if any). Such a member is called a
>   bit-field;<sup>124)</sup> its width is preceded by a colon.
>
> ¶10 A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the
>   specified number of bits.<sup>125)</sup> If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of
>   type `_Bool`, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored; a `_Bool`
>   bit-field has the semantics of a `_Bool`.
>
> ¶11 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.
>
> ¶12 A bit-field declaration with no declarator, but only a colon and a width, indicates an
>   unnamed bit-field.<sup>126)</sup> As a special case, a bit-field structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no further bit-field is to be packed into the unit in which the previous bitfield, if any, was placed.
>
> <sup>122)</sup> While the number of bits in a `_Bool` object is at least `CHAR_BIT`, the width (number of sign and value bits) of a `_Bool` may be just 1 bit.
>
> <sup>123)</sup> A structure or union cannot contain a member with a variably modified type because member names are not ordinary identifiers as defined in 6.2.3.
>
> <sup>124)</sup> The unary `&` (address-of) operator cannot be applied to a bit-field object; thus, there are no pointers to or arrays of bit-field objects.
>
> <sup>125)</sup> As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is `int` or a typedef-name defined as `int`, then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.
>
> <sup>126)</sup> An unnamed bit-field structure member is useful for padding to conform to externally imposed layouts.

Note ¶11 in particular:

> *The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.*

Note, too, that 'implementation-defined' means that the implementation *must* define what it does.  That is, you can inspect documentation and the documentation *must* tell you what the compiler does (if the compiler is standard-compliant).  This is different from 'unspecified' and some of the other terms you'll encounter — a compiler-writer would almost certainly not change the behaviour of bit-fields casually from release to release.  In contrast, the way that arguments to functions are evaluated, for example, could change from release to release, or according to optimization options chosen at compile time, etc.

> **§6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>
> There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call. Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.<sup>94)</sup>
>
> <sup>94)</sup> In other words, function executions do not ‘‘interleave’’ with each other.
>
> **6.7.2 Type specifiers**
>
> 5 Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.

Comment: you mean it will vary on compiler to compiler ? and i should not depend on this?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: i would think **bit field memory management**  varies from machine to machine and not with compiler to compiler.
same compiler on different machine may behave differently but not the otherwise.

Comment: You need to look at whether the ABI (application binary interface) for the machine (hardware and operating system combination) mandates the bit-field layout. If it does, there is a high probability that the compilers all conform to the ABI.  If the ABI is silent, different compilers may do as they please; the C standard says they can and the ABI does not overrule it.  You still have to read the compiler documentation to know whether it adheres to the ABI (and what it does, whichever standard it follows).

Comment: GCC docs state that _the order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit [is] determined by ABI_ **[4.9 Structures, unions, enumerations, and bit-fields]**, and the ELF x86_64 psABI states that _bit-fields are allocated from right to left._ **[3.1.2 Data Representation]**

Comment: @ninjalj: thanks — that's useful information.  It's sorely tempting to trot out the jibe "that's the wonderful thing about standards; there are so many to choose from".  It can be hard to know which standard is influencing each decision by a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

bit fields are non portable and machine dependent.

Limitations of using bit fields

When using bit fields, be aware of the following issues:

1. The code will be non-portable since the organization of
   bits-within-bytes and bytes-within-words is **machine dependent**.
2. You cannot take the address of a bit field; so the expression
   &mystruct.x is illegal if x is a bit field identifier, because there
   is no guarantee that mystruct.x lies at a byte address.
3. Bit fields are used to pack more variables into a smaller data
   space, but causes the compiler to generate additional code to
   manipulate these variables. This costs in terms of code size and
   execution time.

Comment: 1. The code *will* be portable, as long as it is internal data structures, and you don't make an extra effort to check the order of the bits.

Comment: bit fields _are_ a standard C tool so, as long as you use what the standard provides, your code will be portable.

Answer (score 1):

For linux on x86 the relevant ABI document can be found [here(pdf)](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/abi386-4.pdf).

Specifically related to bitfields:

> ‘‘Plain’’ bit-fields (that is, those neither `signed` nor `unsigned`) always have nonnegative values. Although they may have type `char`, `short`, `int`, or `long` (which can have negative values), these bit-fields have the same range as a bit-field of the same size with the corresponding `unsigned` type.
>
> Bit-fields obey the same size and alignment rules as other structure and union members, with the following additions:
>
> Bit-fields are allocated from right to left (least to most significant).
>   A bit-field must entirely reside in a storage unit appropriate for its declared
>   type. Thus a bit-field never crosses its unit boundary.
>
> Bit-fields may share a storage unit with other `struct` / `union` members,
>   including members that are not bit-fields. Of course, `struct` members
>   occupy different parts of the storage unit.
>   Unnamed bit-fields’ types do not affect the alignment of a structure or
>   union, although individual bit-fields’ member offsets obey the alignment
>   constraints.

The