# How Are Little Endian Structs With Bitfields and Longwords Stored?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields, endianness

So, I can understand that a word of 0x1234, when stored as little-endian, becomes 0x3412 in memory. I am also seeing that byte 0x12 as a bitfield a:4 and b:4 would be stored as 0x21. But what if I have something more complex? Data like 0x1700581001FFFFFF with the following struct ordering? I'm seeing the data stored as 0x7180051001FFFFFF which is making very little sense to me. It seems 'a' and 'b' got swapped but they remained at the beginning of the struct and g remained at the end along with other seemingly random swaps. Why? Also, I left the "LONGWORD" denotion because that is there in the code. I'm not sure how 4 bits can be a longword, but perhaps that has something to do with this craziness?

```
LONGWORD a: 4
LONGWORD b: 4
LONGWORD c: 4
LONGWORD d: 12
LONGWORD e: 8
LONGWORD f: 8
LONGWORD g: 24
```

Comment: it does **not** become 0x3412. The value is still 0x1234 but it's stored as 2 bytes in order 0x34 0x12

Comment: I said "becomes 0x3412 IN MEMORY" which is true. But when interpreted, it is still 0x1234.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677235/bit-fields-memory-management-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon re-reading the documentation, I do not see any allowance for packing the bitfields in simply any order. There is indeed a specified ordering but it is implementation dependent in which way it is done. But it is still quite determinable. In short, from what I am seeing, it is packing up the bits by groups of 8 IN ORDER. The difference for our Little Endian compiler (or maybe some option somewhere) is that the concatenation of the bits puts the first-defined bits AFTER the next-defined bits (i.e. made the first defined less significant than the next-defined). For example:

```
a:3 = 111 (binary)
b:4 = 0000 (binary)
c:9 = 011111111 (binary)
```

Our Little Endian compiler (or, again, perhaps some other option) will take the 3 bits from 'a' and concatenate with b by adding 'a' to the end of 'b'. This, I believe, is opposite what Big Endian compilers would do which would put 'a' before the 'b'. So I'm speculating it's the endianness that does this, but ours would get 7 bits of 0000111 by making ba rather than ab. It then needs one more bit from c to create a full 8. It takes the least significant bit of 'c' which is a 1 and, again, the previous bits get tacked on to the end of that new bit. So we have 10000111. This byte, 0x87, is then stored to memory and it grabs another 8 bits. In this example the next 8 bits is 01111111 and so it stores that byte, 0x7F, after the 0x87. So in memory we now have 0x877F. Another method (likely Big Endian) would have ended up with 0xE0FF. The 0x877F which is now in memory, if interpreted as a word in Little Endian would be a value of 0x7F87 or, in binary, 0111111110000111. This happens to be the exact reverse of the data structure above concatenating 'cba'.

So let's do that same reverse ordering of the data I provided earlier:
(0x1700581001FFFFFF was meant to be parsed as below but I guess that might not have been obvious since it is a Big Endian construct I assumed)

```
LONGWORD a: 4 = 0x1
LONGWORD b: 4 = 0x7
LONGWORD c: 4 = 0x0
LONGWORD d: 12 = 0x058
LONGWORD e: 8 = 0x10
LONGWORD f: 8 = 0x01
LONGWORD g: 24 = 0xFFFFFF
```

With the Little Endian configuration we have, this could be interpreted as one giant structure with a value of 0xFFFFFF0110058071 by concatenating in the order gfedcba. If we store this back to memory in Little Endian format, we would get 0x7180051001FFFFFF which is the exact data I said we were seeing. Big Endian, in theory, would have done it in the order I assumed as obvious (0x1700581001FFFFFF) both as interpreted and stored.

Well, it makes sense to me. Hopefully it makes sense to someone else trying to figure out the same thing! I still don't get why they all say LONGWORD before them though...

Answer (score 3):

In an "implementation-defined manner".  Per **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**, paragraph 11, of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
>   enough to hold a bit-field.  If enough space remains, a bit-field
>   that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be
>   packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.  If insufficient space
>   remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next
>   unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined.  The order
>   of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or
>   low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.  The alignment of
>   the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

To answer your question *But what if I have something more complex? Data like 0x1700581001FFFFFF with the following struct ordering?*

The proper answer in that case, if you want portable and reliable code, is to **not use bit-fields**.  The fact that you have failed to provide enough information in your question for anyone to provide an answer as to how that data will be placed into the bit-fields you described should inform you what the problems are when using bit-fields.

For example, given your bit-fields

```
LONGWORD a: 4
LONGWORD b: 4
LONGWORD c: 4
LONGWORD d: 12
LONGWORD e: 8
LONGWORD f: 8
LONGWORD g: 24
```

If one assumes 16-bit `int`-type values are used for bit-fields, it would be perfectly proper to lay out the data thusly:

```
16-bit `int` with `c`,`b`,`a` - in that order
16-bit `int` with `d`
16-bit `int` with `f`,`e` - in that order
16-bit `int` with first 16 bits of `g`
16-bit `int` with last 8 bits of `g` - **after** 8 bits of padding.
```

And that's not even getting into endianness of the storage.

Comment: I included all information I understood to be relevant. So anything lacking doesn't inform me of anything since I'm not sure what's lacking. I understood the entire point of a bitfield is to designate, in order, the meaning of bits to data. Is this not particularly true? Can it store it however it finds most beneficial and it just remembers where it put it all when referencing it by name?

Comment: @CodeMonkey *I understood the entire point of a bitfield is to designate, in order, the meaning of bits to data.*  Bit-fields most certainly do not designate any order to data.  They can not be used, for example, as part of a union in order to interpret a `char` array of raw data, for example.  They might work on one implementation and fail disastrously on another with no code changes.  Even changing compilier optimization levels can change how a `struct` is laid out in memory.

Comment: Well crap. i guess that explains it then :-P. Now to find out if that's a problem... Thanks! :-)

Comment: @CodeMonkey - *Well crap. i guess that explains it then :-P. Now to find out if that's a problem...*  if you have a specific problem, you're usually better off actually stating what the problem is, providing the code and sample output.

Comment: I don't have a specific problem. As I stated, I have to figure out if this does pose a problem because I do not yet know if it does.

Comment: The advice that "if you want portable and reliable code, to not use bit-fields" can be misleading.  Bit-fields are no less portable than any other C data structure.  If all you do with your bit-field is write to and read from it in C code, it's perfectly portable.  If you try to write or read it to or from the outside world, however, you're going to have terrible portability problems -- but they're exactly the same portability problems you always have with size, endianness, and alignment.

Comment: @CodeMonkey "Can it store it however it finds most beneficial and it just remembers where it put it all when referencing it by name?"  Yes.  That's exactly it.  Couldn't have put it better myself. (And to a very real extent that's what the compiler does with every piece of data you declare and every line of code you write.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I had thought my answer was pretty clearly in response to the OP's question about using bit fields to match an ordered set of binary data, such as one stored in an array of `char`:  *The proper answer in that case, if you want portable and reliable code, is to not use bit-fields.*

Comment: Bit-fields have long struck me as being an almost-useful part of C.  What would be necessary to make them genuinely be useful would be a means of *specifying* the required layout.  Other than chicken-and-egg issues, there shouldn't be any problem; if a compiler needs to be able to access bitfields of any size up the maximum, at any bit offset within a word, for bitfields it places itself, adding support for directives to explicitly set the order should be simple by comparison, and would allow them to be usable in portable code.

Answer (score 2):

Questions like (and the point made in a comment about how to "designate, in order, the meaning of bits to data") inevitably boil down to: *what are you trying to do with the data?*

If you're declaring a data structure so that some C code can write to it, and other C code can read from it, you rarely if ever care about the byte order, or the bitfield order (or the padding, or the alignment, or any of that).

Where it gets tricky -- very tricky -- is when you try to take that data structure, as your C compiler laid it out in memory, and write it out to or read it in from the outside world.  When you try to do that, you end up having to worry forever about type sizes, and byte order, and padding, and alignment, and the order in which bitfields are assigned.

In fact there are so many things to worry about, and nailing them all down is such a nuisance, that many people (myself included) recommend simply not trying to define data structures which can be directly read and written in this way, at all.

My memory is that compilers for big-endinan machines tend to lay out the bits in bitfields one way, and for little-endian the other way.  But I can never remember which way is which.  (And even if I thought I could remember, you shouldn't trust me.)  If for some reason you care, you're going to have to do what I always do, which is to write some little test programs to construct some binary data and print it out in hex and figure out how it's done for the machine/compiler combination you're using today.  (And of course you also have to decide what you're going to do about the possibility that your machine/compiler combination might change next week.)